# Not Shutting Down

Tags: 13.04, shutdown, uefi

Using Raring Ringtail on Acer V5 (UEFI Bios mode). The system simply refuses to shut down. I have tried the 
`sudo poweroff`
as well as shutting down from the system menu. Each time it just reboots after shutting down (whether plugged in or on battery).

Comment: Is this dual boot, or just **13.04**?

Comment: Update to the latest kernel `sudo apt-get update upgrade`.

Comment: I have Windows 8 in UEFI mode. It's strictly speaking not a dual boot, like once I press the power button, it starts Ubuntu. If I want to start windows, I have to go to bios with F2, change some settings (which I can't recall) and then it starts with Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried `sudo shutdown -h now` from a terminal?

The optional -h is to "put all harddrives on the system in standby mode just before halt or poweroff."

Comment: Also try (minor variant): **`sudo shutdown -P now`**

Comment: Tried both of them, same result.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "reboot_type=k" to the kernel's boot options. You can do this on a test basis in GRUB by hitting "e" to edit the kernel options, or by hitting F2 or Insert twice in rEFInd. If this works and you want to use this setting permanently, you'll need to adjust your boot loader configuration. Something called "GRUB Customizer" should do the job if you're using GRUB, but I've never used this myself, so I can't provide more details of how to use it. Editing `/boot/refind_linux.conf` should enable you to add this option permanently if you're using rEFInd.